# python script freezed with cx_freeze crashes when creating a new multiprocessing process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cx-freeze

**The Program:**

```
import multiprocessing
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="freeze_test.log", level=logging.DEBUG)


def do(nothing, more_nothing):
    logging.info("process executed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    logging.info("start freeze test")
    multiprocessing.Process(target=do, args=("something", "more_something")).start()
```

**The cx_freeze setup:**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "freeze_test",
    options = {"build_exe":{"packages":["multiprocessing"]}},
    executables = [Executable(script="freeze_test.py", base = "win32GUI")]
)
```

Running the programm unfrozen works just fine...
**Running the frozen programm gives me those Errors:**

[image: ERROR 1]
[image: ERROR 2]

I use python 3.7 on windows 10...
I'm really stuck with this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Edit:
>   In the [documentation about multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) it says that the 'spawn' and 'forkserver' start methods can't be used with freezed programs, however you have to use 'spawn' on Windows. - So is it currently impossible to use multiprocessing with frozen programs on Windows?